# Reduce memory usage while dumping Access table to CSV

Tags: php, csv, ms-access, wamp

I'm using this simple code to read an 80 MB .mdb file and converting it to CSV on a WAMP enviroment, but I'm experiencing surprisingly high memory usage (more than 512 MB)

Is there any way to split the loading in pieces or some other way to avoid such a high memory usage?

```
$conn = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=$mdbFilename", $user, $password);

$qry = "SELECT * FROM data";

$result = odbc_exec($conn,$qry);

$theArray = array();

while ( ($row = odbc_fetch_array($result)) )
   {
      array_push($theArray, $row);
   }

$fp = fopen('dispo_e.csv', 'w');
foreach ($theArray as $lines) 
{
    fputcsv($fp, $lines, ";");
}
```

Comment: If you like any of the answers, be sure you vote up and click the ticket beside your favourite *(shameless self-promotion)*

Answer (score 2):

Easiest option is to not assign it to an array, but rather, just write directly to the CSV.

```
$conn = odbc_connect(
    "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=$mdbFilename",
    $user,
    $password
);

$result = odbc_exec($conn, 'SELECT * FROM data');

$fp = fopen('dispo_e.csv', 'w');
while (($row = odbc_fetch_array($result))) {
    fputcsv($fp, $lines, ';');
}

fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score -1):

You might try this function instead(usage below):

```
<?php
    function query_to_csv($db_conn, $query, $filename, $attachment = false, $headers = true) {

        if($attachment) {
            // send response headers to the browser
            header( 'Content-Type: text/csv' );
            header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='.$filename);
            $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
        } else {
            $fp = fopen($filename, 'w');
        }

        $result = mysql_query($query, $db_conn) or die( mysql_error( $db_conn ) );

        if($headers) {
            // output header row (if at least one row exists)
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            if($row) {
                fputcsv($fp, array_keys($row));
                // reset pointer back to beginning
                mysql_data_seek($result, 0);
            }
        }

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            fputcsv($fp, $row);
        }

        fclose($fp);
    }

    // Using the function
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
    // $db_conn should be a valid db handle

    // output as an attachment
    query_to_csv($db_conn, $sql, "test.csv", true);

    // output to file system
    query_to_csv($db_conn, $sql, "test.csv", false);
?>
```

Comment: So you just copied a piece of code you have! What has it got to do with the OP's question? Nothing! You should answer the question, not change the question to fit an answer you think you may have.